# How to select from different columns conditionally in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an pandas DataFrame like shaped Nx5

```
['','','A','','']
['','C','','','']
['','A','','','']
['','','','T','']
.
.
.
```

I want to convert it to Nx1 shape getting non-empty values

```
['A']
['C']
['A']
['T']
.
.
.
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Do you want a pandas solution or a pythonic one?

Comment: Pandas solution is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `"".join` for every row:

```
df.apply("".join, axis=1)
```

If you are not sure every row has only one not empty value, following method is better:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['','','A','',''],
    ['','C','','',''],
    ['','A','','',''],
    ['','','','T','']]
)

s = df.stack()
print s[s!=""]
```

output:

```
0  2    A
1  1    C
2  1    A
3  3    T
dtype: object
```

for more than one column:

```
r = s[s!=""]
r.groupby(level=0).apply(pd.DataFrame.reset_index, drop=True).unstack()
```

Comment: Thanks, that is precise